# Flutter/RiverPod -when in the build/setup process is it correct to push an initial value into a provider that acts as a filter to a search provider?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have two providers in my Flutter app - a filter provider that holds a string search filter value, and then a second search provider that uses the filter provider as an input.

My question concerns how/where is best to setup the initial value for the filter provider?  In my case I want to pull a 'last used filter value' from a database query and set this into the filter provider.

I've tried this in various locations, and keep getting errors about how setting values into a provider is not allowed during the build process.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Save it in shared preferences.  Fetch it from there in the first build() of your filter provider.  Store it when it updates.

Answer (score 0):

To initialise the filter provider with the cached filter value, you may load it from the database inside the build method.

To update the filter, you can set the state of the provider to the new filter value and then save the updated filter to the database.

If you are using shared_preferences and riverpod code generation, you can define a filter provider as below.

```dart
@riverpod
class Filter extends _$Filter {
  @override
  String? build() {
    // set the initial state of the provider by returning
    // the value retrieved from shared preferences or other databases
    final sharedPreferences = ref.watch(sharedPreferencesProvider);
    final cachedValue = sharedPreferences.getString('filter');
    return cachedValue;
  }

  Future<void> setFilter(String filter) async {
    state = filter;
    // save the filter to shared preferences or other database
    final sharedPreferences = ref.watch(sharedPreferencesProvider);
    await sharedPreferences.setString('filter', filter);
  }
}
```